# What is the difference between float pointer and int pointer address?

Tags: c, pointers

I tried to run this code,

```
int *p;
float q;
q = 6.6;
p = &q;
```

Though it will be a warning, but i think `&q` and `p` are of same size, so `p` can have an address of `q`. But when I print `&q` and `p` I am getting different output.
This is my output

```
*p =  6.600000 
 q = 0.000000, p = 0x40d33333, &q = 0x7fffe2fa3c8c
```

What is that I am missing?
And `p` and `&q` is same when both pointer and variable type is same.

My complete code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{   
    int *p;
    float q;
    q = 6.6;
    p = &q;
    printf("*p =  %f \n q = %f, p = %p, &q = %p \n",*p,q,p,&q);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using to get that output.

Comment: If I get you right, you might want to use a union...

Comment: It's `int main(void)`, not `void main()`. `void main()` is useful mostly for detecting books written by authors who don't know C very well.

Comment: You're runing on x86_64? Then what probably happens in `printf("*p =  %f \n q = %f, p = %p, &q = %p \n",*p,q,p,&q);` is that the putative `int` `*p` is passed in a general purpose register, the `double` (the promoted value of `q`) is passed in a floating point register, the two pointers again in general purpose registers.

Comment: Then `printf` reads the first floating point register for the first `%f` conversion, the second floating point register for the second `%f` [coincidentally that contains 0], the first general purpose register - that contains the bits of the `float` 6.6 - to print `p`, and the second general purpose register (containing the value of `p`) to print `&q`. The register containing the address of `q` remains unread.

Comment: @KeithThompson I know int main(void) should be used always. But in this program it doesn't really matter. My main question is pointer can be of any type, but it will hold the address. Then forget about the size of that datatype, why is address different? And I even know I'm trying to use int* with float, but I'm just experimenting with pointers.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, you are right. I split the `printf` in to parts
first one for `values` and second one for `addresses`. And the problem was with `%f`, what I thought was if `p` contains address of `float` it will still work if I give `%f` in `printf` statement. But it loads data in general purpose register this problem is happening. After I split, I got correct addresses but values are still different. Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: @RohitO: If you know `int main(void)` should always be used, then I suggest you *always use it*; at the very least, it will avoid complaints from people like me. As for why `int*` and `float*` are distinct types, I've just added a couple of paragraphs to my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to take compiler warnings more seriously.

C doesn't require compilers to *reject* invalid programs, it merely requires "diagnostics" for rule violations. A diagnostic can be either a fatal error message or a warning.

Unfortunately, it's common for compilers to issue warnings for assignments of incompatible pointer types.

```
void main()
```

This is wrong; it should be `int main(void)`. Your compiler may let you get away with it, and it may not cause any visible problems, but there's no point in not writing it correctly. (It's not *quite* that simple, but that's close enough.)

```
int *p;
float q;
q = 6.6;
```

That's ok.

```
p = &q;
```

`p` is of type `int*`; `&q` is of type `float*`. Assigning one to the other (without a cast) is a *constraint violation*. The simplest way to look at it is that it's simply illegal.

If you really want to do this assignment, you can use a cast:

```
p = (int*)&q; /* legal, but ugly */
```

but there's rarely a good reason to do so.  `p` is a pointer to `int`; it should point to an `int` object unless you have a *very* good reason to make it point to something else. In some circumstances, the conversion itself can have undefined behavior.

```
printf("*p =  %f \n q = %f, p = %p, &q = %p \n",*p,q,p,&q);
```

The `%f` format requires a `double` argument (a `float` argument is promoted to `double` in this context so `float` would be ok). But `*p` is of type `int`. Calling `printf` with an argument of the wrong type causes your program's behavior to be undefined.

`%p` requires an argument of type `void*`, not just of any pointer type. If you want to print a pointer value, you should cast it to `void*`:

```
printf("&q = %p\n", (void*)&q);
```

It's likely to work without the cast, but again, the behavior is undefined.

If you get any warnings when you compile a program, don't even bother running it. Fix the warnings first.

As for the question in your title, pointers of type `int*` and `float*` are of different types. An `int*` should point to an `int` object; a `float*` should point to a `float` object. Your compiler may let you mix them, but the result of doing so is either implementation-defined or undefined. The C language, and particularly many C compilers, will let you get away with a lot of things that don't make much sense.

The reason that they're distinct types is to (try to) prevent, or at least detect, errors in their use. If you declare an object of type `int*`, you're saying that you intend for it to point to an `int` object (if it's not a null pointer). Storing the address of a `float` object in your `int*` object is almost certainly a mistake. Enforcing type safety allows such mistakes to be detected as early as possible (when your compiler prints a warning rather than when your program crashes during a demo for an important client).

It's likely (but not guaranteed) that `int*` and `float*` are the same size and have the same internal representation. But the *meaning* of an `int*` object is not "a collection of 32 (or 64) bits containing a virtual address", but "something that points to an `int` object".

Comment: Since you're throwing the book at him, reading `*p` violates strict aliasing, so it's UB in itself regardless of what you do with the value.

Comment: `p = (int *) & q;` is not always legal. C 2011 (n1570) 6.3.2.3 7 says the behavior is undefined if the result is not correctly aligned. It will be on typical current platforms, so this is okay if you are planning your target accordingly but not if you are planning for standard C or want to understand the semantics of the C specification.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Correct -- except that it's not clear what "legal" means in this context (the standard never uses that word). I've updated my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson When will be the size of `int*` and `float*` may differ? I thought address will always be of fixed size, regardless of datatype. Or is there any case in which `int` is stored in different memory and `float` is stored in different memory.?

Comment: @RohitO: It's very likely that `int*` and `float*` will be the same size -- but the C standard doesn't require it. Another example: there are systems that are word-addressed, so a machine address points to a full word (say, 4 or 8 bytes) -- but a `char*` consists of a machine address plus an offset within the word. You're not likely to run into such a system -- but you're also not likely to need to *care* about the relative sizes of `int*` and `float*`. If you need the size of an `int*` just write `sizeof (int*)` (or, more likely, `sizeof some_pointer_object`).

Comment: Downvoter: If there's a problem with this answer, please leave a comment explaining it.

Comment: Implementations may accept `void main()`.  It's only "wrong" in the sense that some other compiler may not accept it , this is a different sort of wrong to a constraint violation which must be diagnosed by all compilers

Comment: @M.M: I acknowledged that it's not quite as simple as it being "wrong". The details have been discussed at length elsewhere. (The problem isn't just that some compilers accept it and others don't. For compilers that don't diagnose it but don't document that they accept it, the behavior is undefined.)

Answer (score 9):

You're getting undefined behaviour, because you're passing the wrong types to `printf`. When you tell it to expect a float, it actually expects a `double` - but you pass an `int`.

As a result it prints the wrong information, because `printf` relies entirely on the format string to access the arguments you pass it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what is said by teppic,

Consider,

```
int a = 5;
int *p = &a;
```

In this case we indicate to the compiler that `p` is going to point to an integer. So it is known that when we do something like `*p` , at runtime, the no. of bytes equal to size of an `int` would be read.

If you assign address of a datatype occupying `x` number of bytes to a pointer of which is declared to hold the address of datatypes of fewer bytes than `x`, you read the wrong number of bytes when using the indirection operator.

Comment: Who says `float` is bigger than `int`? It's allowed to be, but probably isn't.

Comment: @Steve Yes, I agree its not always the case. But some systems it is that way.   By bigger i meant occupies more bytes. Maybe my example isn't the best one, to put my point through. I just wanted to indicate that we define the type of pointer for a reason [just like we have to typecast `void` pointer before using indirection on it]

Comment: I suggest that the size is not the point. I've worked on systems where `sizeof (int) == sizeof (double)`; the program's behavior is equally undefined on such a system. You risk giving the impression that mixing pointer types like this is ok if the sizes happen to match. And `p` specifically needs to point to an `int`, not just any integer.

Comment: Actually, i wanted to indicate that its not safe to mismatch pointer types and the datatype it points  to.