# Binary to Float

Tags: c, floating-point, binary

I wanted to produce float variables from their binary representation, and I quickly came up with the following code:

```
float bintofloat(unsigned int x) {
    float *f = (float *)&x;
    return *f;
}
```

The above function can then be called as follows:

```
float f = bintofloat(0x3f800000);
```

I was just hoping to get some opinions on this approach: whether using pointers is the best method, or whether there is a better or more concise method?

Unfortunately, my use of types seems to have caused a distraction. I apologise for this; I chose to stick with built-in types for the sake of simplicity. But I do recognise that it is naive, and assumes that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`.

Again, my primary question is whether the use of pointers is a good way to achieve this translation from binary to floating-point?

Comment: I am not sure, but did you figure out if endianness can be a issue or not?

Comment: Not valid, because size of `unsigned int` may not be equals to size of `float` first, and address in `f` in `bintofloat()` is not basically address of `float`, so  `*f`  causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : `unsigned int` is always `4` bytes on 32 and 64 bit `gcc` compilers. Isn't it? And `float` as per IEEE 754 standard must be `4` bytes.

Comment: @MadHatter anyways, sizeof `float*` may not  = sizeof `unsigned int*`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : Both are pointers for `C`, how can then both differ in size.

Comment: @MadHatter I learn so sometime in past, I didn't find a link except this [Does the size of pointers vary in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520059/does-the-size-of-pointers-vary-in-c)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51336/discussion-between-madhatter-and-grijesh-chauhan)

Comment: This would usually work, but Strict Aliasing doesn't have to like this so I would suggest `memcpy` (don't worry, it should be optimized away).

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, I should have made this clear. I am aware of the sizing issues of `int` vs. `float` on diff architectures. I chose to stick with built-in types for the sake of simplicity, but were I to implement this properly, I would switch to something like `uint32_t`.

Comment: @MadHatter I added an answer. you may like to check.

Comment: Better to use `union` than pointers.  This takes care of many issues: `float bintofloat(uint32_t x) { union { uint32_t u; float f; } tmp = { x }; assert(sizeof(float)==sizeof(uint32_t)); return tmp.f; }`.

Comment: Endian-ness will not keep code from "working", but code may generate different answers on different platforms.  Endian-ness of a `float` is not _required_ to be the same as `int`, but often is the same.  Note: `float` is not required to be IEEE and results may vary due to FP encoding.

Comment: @chux Thanks for your comment. I do like the `union` solution. However, I'm still unsure of its potential to handle any alignment issues, as suggested below?!

Comment: The `union` will provide proper alignment for the fields and the `assert()` will insure the same size.  No pointer casting is involved.

Comment: @chux Thanks. I would generally assume that two variables `x` and `y` would have the same alignment under the assumption `sizeof(x) == sizeof(y)`; I'm not sure how you would sensibly align them differently. However, I'd never read any documentation which actually made this guarantee.

Comment: True, `float` _could_ be more than 32 bits (36) and `uint32_t` is padded on some esoteric 36-bit machine, thus their sizes are same, but with padding involved,  `bintofloat()` fails to set all bits of the `float`.  On such esoteric machines, `uint32_t` may not be defined (hard to implement) and code gladly fails to compile there. IMO, there's no real chance of alignment issue with union, given the code compiles and `uint32_t` and sizes match. I suppose pedantic code would `assert(sizeof (uint64_t) > sizeof(uint32_t)` to insure not compiling on a 64-bit size only for all integer and FP machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I should document that my preferred answer is to use `memcpy`, as suggested by @harold in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265265/binary-to-float?noredirect=1#comment35605548_23265265). Unfortunately, I'm unable to directly accept a comment as being the answer to my question.

For reference, a solution using `memcpy` may look something like the following:

```
float bintofloat(uint32_t x) {
    float f = 0.0f;
    memcpy(&f, &x, sizeof(f) < sizeof(x) ? sizeof(f) : sizeof(x));
    return f;
}
```

Although the `memcpy` solution is my preferred answer, I'd also like to recognise that another nice solution was suggested which makes use of a `union`: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265265/binary-to-float?noredirect=1#comment35613266_23265265) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23267400/779071).

Comment: you can accept your own answer on SO (it is valid).

Comment: Thank you, I realise that I can accept my own answer. However, there is a waiting period before I can do so (another 11 hours, at present). What I was attempting to make clear is that it is @harold who deserves credit for this answer, not me. And I that would have accepted his [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265265/binary-to-float/23276212#comment35605548_23265265) as the answer, rather than write and accept my own answer, if that were possible.

Comment: I din't know to accept our-own answer there is to long wait. (I ever answered my self :P)

Answer (score 5):

In your code, in function `bintofloat()` following address casting and dereferencing is invalid:

```
float *f = (float *)&x;
return *f;
```

This will call undefined behavior at runtime.

> #### [EXP36-C. Do not cast pointers into more strictly aligned pointer types](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP36-C.+Do+not+cast+pointers+into+more+strictly+aligned+pointer+types)
>
> **Do not convert a pointer value to a pointer type that is more strictly aligned than the referenced type. Different alignments are possible for different types of objects**. If the type-checking system is overridden by an explicit cast or the pointer is converted to a void pointer `(void *)` and then to a different type, the alignment of an object may be changed.
>
> > The C Standard, 6.3.2.3, paragraph 7 [ISO/IEC 9899:2011], states:
> >
> > A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different object or incomplete type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.
>
> If the *misaligned pointer is dereferenced, the program may terminate abnormally. On some architectures, the cast alone may cause a loss of information even if the value is not dereferenced if the types involved have differing alignment requirements*.

In your code `x` is unsigned int  that has different memory alignments then float types.

Type conversion `float *f = (float *)&x;` is valid but not good idea in general. A float type pointer should point to float type. Some systems may even give the program a fatal SIGBUS when deferencing an unsigned int* as a float* because float require more strict address alignment to a multiple of sizeof(float).

When you what to write generic code then approved way to assign address of unknown type is using `void*`, but to derefrence you have to convert into correct type back so in fact following code is wrong:

```
unsigned int x = 10U;
unsigned int *xp = &x; 
void* vp = x;
float* fp = vp;
float f = *fp;
```

The [link](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP36-C.+Do+not+cast+pointers+into+more+strictly+aligned+pointer+types) from where I quoted give you some more examples that will help you to understand the issue.

You should also read this [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson)'s answer: [What is the difference between float pointer and int pointer address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790980/what-is-the-difference-between-float-pointer-and-int-pointer-address)

Edit: I think you can do something like as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
float bintofloat(unsigned int x) {
    union {
        unsigned int  x;
        float  f;
    } temp;
    temp.x = x;
    return temp.f;
}

int main(){
    float f = bintofloat(0x4236AE14U);
    printf ("\nf = %f ", f);
    printf ("\nf = %f \n", bintofloat(0x4287F0A4U));    
    return 0;
}
```

Use it as:

```
$ gcc -Wall -pedantic binarytofloat.c
taxspanner@:~$ ./a.out 

f = 45.669998 
f = 67.970001
```

Check following float Precision IEEE754 calculator's Links:

1. [0x4236AE14U](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=052053046054055)
2. [0x4287F0A4U](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=054055046057055)

Comment: Your link to the Stack Overflow answer seems to suggest similar code to what I already have?! Rather than switching from `int` to `float`, it's switching from `float` to `int`, but has the line `p = (int*)&q; /* legal, but ugly */`
Do you have an alternate/better recommendation to do this, without using `alignas`, which avoids alignment issues?

Comment: By the way, I'm compiling with Clang. And I've compiled with `clang -Weverything...`, but I do not receive any warnings about the casting or alignment.

Comment: @greydamian The [link](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP36-C.+Do+not+cast+pointers+into+more+strictly+aligned+pointer+types) says `float f = (float)x;` is compliant solution. But presently I don't have any idea how would you use this for binary to float conversion.

Comment: @greydamian You can do something like [I did binary to float](http://codepad.org/YjiZYYfq)

Comment: I did read both links, and the code to which I referred was in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790980/what-is-the-difference-between-float-pointer-and-int-pointer-address).
Unfortunately, the code `float f = (float)x` does exactly what I'm trying to avoid, as it would "convert" `0x3f800000` to `1065353216.0f`.

Comment: @greydamian No `float f = (float)x` is not same as you did in your code, I updated my answer With some code suggestion read.

Comment: Thanks for your code. I do like your `union` solution. However, I'm unsure of its potential to handle any alignment issues. Therefore, I'm currently leaning towards the `memcpy` method.

Comment: I realise `float f = (float)x` is not what I did in my code. Because that is not the behaviour that I want. As I said, that's "exactly what I'm trying to avoid."

Comment: @greydamian Yes, and `memcpy` is smart enough to handle memory alignment issues for us, Hence you can also accomplice same thing using memcpy check [this code at codepad](http://codepad.org/1YNmlj42)

Comment: I read your answer, the `union` method is much clean and less disputed. +1.

Comment: Please do not cite from https://www.securecoding.cert.org/ as if it were normative.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Ok, I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to learn how floating point numbers are handled in binary number representation. Follow the standard IEEE 754 format of conversion this should help you get started,

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point_representation.html

http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm

Comment: You are referring him to some links, but you didn't mention why? What did you find wrong in OP's implementation?

Comment: @MadHatter Akash means, how to interpreter binary represent as a  float number, So he is suggesting IEEE format that says how floating point numbers are handled in binary number representation.

Comment: I appreciate the response; and I do understand IEEE 754 representation, and endianness. However, I don't wish to "interpret" or convert the binary representation in any way, I simply wish to take a sequence of bits and map that on to a float variable for the machine on which the code is being run.