# Is pointer to a pointer which points to a float or a char always an int?

Tags: c, pointers

if c is of float type and *p is a pointer to c. * p should also be of float type. but it **p2 is a pointer to *p . should it be an int type??because all the " * " says is that " value at adress " is of int type (in case of **p2)
like :

```
float s=10.50 ; 
float *p ;
*p=&s ;
float **p2=&(*p);
```

Should the above line be float or an int type since the value stored at *p is the address of s(which is an integer)?

Comment: A pointer to a pointer is a pointer. It is not an `int`.

Comment: Unless you're addressing dereferenced iterators in C++, `&(*anything)` is a near-guaranteed sign the wheels fell off. That should be `float **p2 = &p;`. the prior line is just-as-wrong. You seem to be of the mind that a pointer cannot appear in an expression without an asterisk.

Comment: Pointers are not integers. Pointers are not numbers. Pointers are pointers.

Comment: `*p=&s` is wrong. Maybe you meant `p=&s`. Then, `&(*p)` is not a `float **`. Maybe you meant `float **p2=&p;`?

Comment: Third line looks suspicious. You are storing value of s in address pointed by p. Shouldn't it be 'p=&s'. And pointers could be of same size of int. But pointers are not integers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between float pointer and int pointer address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790980/what-is-the-difference-between-float-pointer-and-int-pointer-address)

Answer (score 0):

One mistake that you are making is that you are *dereferencing a pointer* when you have the command

```
float **p2=&(*p);
```

Instead, what you want to write down there is:

```
float **p2=&p;
```

so that you can have a pointer to a pointer of a float.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is an address in memory. And the address could be of float variable, an int variable or a structure of many such variables. But pointer is always pointer, not int or anything else. It could be of same size as integer on some architectures.

So p2 here is a pointer not float. And even p is a pointer.

Lets analyze the code:

```
 *p=&s;
```

Though this will give compiler warnings(incompatible assignment), you are copying address of s to place pointed by p. p here could be garbage and you are potentially copying address of s to some garbage address.

Address of s could be of bigger size than int. size of int is 4 byte and address of s(int) could be 8 byte. (On some architectures)

```
float **p2=&(*p);
```

Above line as same as
    float **p2 = p;

So p2 has same value as p which is some garbage uninitialized address.

Answer (score 0):

The asterisks are part of the C type.
So the three variables you've defined are of types:

```
(float)
(float *)
(float **)
```

Each star means an extra level of indirection or a pointer. The 'float' part always means the thing you end up with after unravelling the pointers. The fact that the CPU might see pointers as an 'int-like' type isn't relevant to how this works.